# some subplots in Plotly loops

Tags: python, loops, charts, plotly

Please help, i need get 3 subplots for one month in subplot.
in my dataframe, i get multiindex (months and names) and values column
i want to put this data in loop and draw Plotly-charts.
Please, help if you can. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

my_months = [9,9,9,10,10,10,11,11,11]
my_vls = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 25, 20, 30, 20]
my_names = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'two', 'three',]
test = pd.DataFrame(zip(my_months, my_names, my_vls), columns=['month','names', 'values'])
test = test.groupby(['month', 'names']).sum()

test_fig = make_subplots(
    rows = len(test.index.levels[0]),
    cols = 1)

months = test.index.levels[0].unique()

for i, month in months:
    vals = test.loc[test.index.get_level_values(0)==month]['values'].unique()
    for j in local_df.index.levels[1]:
        local_df_2 = local_df.loc[local_df.index.get_level_values(1)==j]
        test_fig.append_trace(
            go.Bar(
                x = local_df_2.index.get_level_values(1),
                y = local_df_2.values), 
            row=i+1, 
            col=1)
        
test_fig.show()
```

i find some SO-links, probably it helps:
[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221266/how-to-loop-to-create-subplots-in-plotly-where-each-subplot-has-a-few-curves-on)
[second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845360/how-can-i-get-all-plotly-plots-created-inside-a-for-loop-display-in-single-brows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is very simple:

```
y = local_df_2.values[0]
```